# How to turn a ping request on postman using curl

Tags: api, postman, garmin

Using Garmin APi, I am trying to use their Ping Service, in the doc they give us an exemple of the request we should do :

```
curl -v -X POST -H “Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8” -d ‘{“epochs”:[{“userAccessToken”:”8f57a6f1-26ba-4b05-a7cd- c6b525a4c7a2”,”uploadStartTimeInSeconds”:1444937651,”uploadEndTimeInSeconds”:1444 937902,”callbackURL”:”https://healthapi.garmin.com/wellness- api/rest/epochs?uploadStartTimeInSeconds=1444937651&uploadEndTimeInSeconds=144493 7902”}]}’ http://localhost:8080/garmin/ping
```

I have no idea how to write it in postman, I have the header this is ok, then we have other value after the -d, don't know where to put it...

I have tried to import the cURL using the import function as in postman but it gives me :

```
Error while importing Curl: arg.startsWith is not a function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use proper quotation marks, `"` and `'` instead of `“`, `”`, `‘` and `’`.

This is working:

```
curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8" -d '{"epochs":[{"userAccessToken":"8f57a6f1-26ba-4b05-a7cd- c6b525a4c7a2","uploadStartTimeInSeconds":1444937651,"uploadEndTimeInSeconds":1444 937902,"callbackURL":"https://healthapi.garmin.com/wellness- api/rest/epochs?uploadStartTimeInSeconds=1444937651&uploadEndTimeInSeconds=144493 7902"}]}' http://localhost:8080/garmin/ping
```